# python naming convention for plugins, i.e. non-top-level packages

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is naming convention for non-top-level python packages, i.e. so called plugins or extensions. According to PyPI the plugins, mostly, named with dash(-) or dot(.)

e.g.:
most django plugins named with dash while plone/zope and many others prefer the dot, WTF? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any such convention, but if there was one it would most probably be `frameworkName-extensionName`. It's the one I've seen used most often.

PyPI's [package index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/) shows a mix of both. Stick to the existing convention whenever possible i.e. if you're developing a Django resusable app, use hyphen (-); for frameworks where plugins use dot (.), use that. If there is no existing convention, you pick :p